# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'itemAttrService' is defined

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, pom.xml, zk

I am trying a example in Spring + Hibernate + ZK framework. I package a war file through pom.xml file. After that when I run the program `on server` It throws the following exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'itemAttrService' is defined

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nagarro</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZKSpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZKSpringHibernateExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

        <!-- ZK Dependency start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkplus</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zhtml</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ZK Dependency Ends -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>DataSyncTreePOC</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/BeanLocations.xml,

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- <error-page> <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> <location>/error/error.zul</location> 
        </error-page> -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/showDbData.zul</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am creating the beans like this

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");
itemAttrService = (ItemAttributeService)appContext.getBean("itemAttrService");
```

I am able to construct a `appContext` but not the `itemAttrService`

`itemAttrService` is declared as follows in the same file

```
@Autowired
private ItemAttributeService itemAttrService
```

I have also used @Service annotation in my service class like this

```
package com.nagarro.service.impl;

@Service("itemAttrService")
public class ItemAttributeServiceImpl implements ItemAttributeService{

code....
}
```

See, this class comes under the `com.nagarro` package so it should be auto-scanned. But, it is not the case here. Please advice whether I am missing something crucial in my `pom.xml` or `web.xml`

Comment: You haven't shown any kind of Spring configuration.

Comment: I have shown dependencies in the pom.xml file. What else should I do?

Comment: Somewhere, you've got a "spring/config/BeanLocations.xml" file that you're loading, which is very likely related to the problem, since it's a Spring problem and that's a Spring config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spring/config/BeanLocations.xml` needs to contain a line like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nagarro.service.impl" />
```